# How to manage memory for autorelease objects

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, autorelease

I work on implementation of playing card class and i've created the following method:

```
+ (id)cardWithCard:(Card *)newCard
{
Card *card = [[[Card alloc] initWithCard:newCard] autorelease];
return card;
}
```

i use autorelease method here cause otherwise Product->Analyze warns me about potential leak. Everything works fine until variable myCard (which was allocated earlier) to which a new value was assigned like this:`myCard = [Card cardWithCard:newCard]` is sent to a different method as a parameter. It turns out to be deallocated there and my app crashes.
How should i resolve this issue? Get autorelease method away despite warnings of Analyze?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each method or object should be responsible for retaining object that it is interested in.
It it easier to maintain. (Exception are for method that have `alloc`, `new` or `copy` in there name, they will return an object that the caller is responsible to `release`.)

So you need to keep the `autorelease` because that method don't exist after the `return` and won't be able to call release on it.
The Object that is calling `cardWithCard` should `retain` the object if it want it to be alive more that the time of that particular method.

The code should look something like this

```
self.myCard = [Card cardWithCard:newCard];
```

This is in the case where `myCard` is declare like this

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) Card * myCard;
```

So in this case the property will do the retain for you and will release that object when you will place a new one in this property. (If you overwrite the auto-generated accessor, you will need to manage that yourself in those method)

If for some reason you don't want to use a property... well it's your choice :-)
You will need to do something like this:

```
myCard = [[Card cardWithCard:newCard] retain];
```

and you will need to something like this later on

```
[myCard release];
```

If it's not in the same method the analyser will compline, and if it's in the same method you probably don't need the `retain`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed explanation. What i've got in practice is the following: when i did these @property (nonatomic, retain) Card * myCard; nothing changed. myCard was still deallocated in the method i pass it to. doing this - myCard = [[Card cardWithCard:newCard] retain]; has fixed the problem, app doesn't crash anymore but now i'm wondering if i have a leak (Analyze says i don't) cause i retain myCard in a loop but release it just once. What do you think? Do i have a leak now?

Comment: @AndreyChernukha DON'T DO THAT!!!! you are bypassing your `@property` you need to do `self.myCard = something` so the property get called and do it's magic. If you do `myCard = something` you are bypassing your `@property` that is why you need the extra `retain`. If you always bypass property don't bother declaring them, but that is not a good way to go, it's more error prone